# Version controller in websocket with fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi

So, I want to use router within the websocket call.
This is what I have, at the moment (using dummy data)

version->v1->**init**.py

```
router.include_router(websocket_controller, prefix="/ws")
router_without_prefix.include_router(websocket_controller)
```

version->v1->websocket_controller.py
So this is the enpoint:

```
router = APIRouter()

@router.websocket("/ws/something")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
```

but I want to remove this line:
`router_without_prefix.include_router(websocket_controller).` But when I remove this line and call the websocket I have a 403. Can someone explain to me how I can correct this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
According to this [FastAPI GitHub issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/98), this issue is specific to websocket routers. Including the router using `include_router` might not work, but adding routes individually works.

Like so: `app.add_websocket_route(path="/ws/something", route=websocket_endpoint)`

---

Old:

Issue: The router has an extra prefix of `/ws`.

You have a prefix of `"/ws"` defined in `init.py`, and the coroutine `websocket_endpoint` is accessed by `"/ws/something"`. This means the async function is available on `"/ws/ws/something"`.

Removing the line, `router_without_prefix.include_router(websocket_controller)`, means you also need to update the `@router.websocket("/ws/something")` line to just `@router.websocket("/something")`, since the router already has the prefix.

Let me know if this works!

Comment: thank you for the help. well I tried this and I continue to have the same error...

Comment: I have updated my answer. Apparently there is a issue with websockets, not present with http :)

Comment: this solution worked, thank you so much for the help :)